# Data from API call and jsonobject is not carrying over when called

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm calling this API and it's jsonobject in a segue, and trying to push it into a view controller, but it's not carrying the data.  In my Below code it prints just fine in the call, but the other two prints come up with null.

Is there something I'm missing to make the data persistent?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showChangeDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
    BNRItem *item = nil;
    //BDItemChangeDetailAPI *itemAPI = nil;
    NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];

    if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        item = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        //item = items[indexPath.row];
        item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    NSLog(@"111111%@", self.APIItem);
    [self fetchFeedAPIChangeDetail];
      NSLog(@"222222%@", self.APIItem);
    BDChangeApproveController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.itemAPI = self.APIItem;


}
}

- (void)fetchFeedAPIChangeDetail
{
//NSString *changeorder = changeOrder;

// NSString *requestString = [@"http://URL.com];

NSString *requestString = @"http://URL.com";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
[self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                completionHandler:
 ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

     NSDictionary *jsonObject1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                options:0
                                                                  error:nil];
     //NSLog(@"%@", jsonObject1);
     self.APIItem = jsonObject1[@"CoDetail"];
     NSLog(@"%@", self.APIItem);
 }];

[dataTask resume];

}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// show loading indicator
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] fetchFeedAPIChangeDetail:^(NSArray *array, NSError *err)
 {
     [weakSelf performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showChangeDetail" sender:weakSelf];
     // hide loading indicator
 }];
}
```

Comment: I guess that in your `NSLog(@"222222%@", self.APIItem);` you have null, since `fetchFeedAPIChangeDetail` use a completion handler. So the fetch will start, but the other lines will continue witouth waiting for the completion.

Comment: Is there a way to make it step through?  If it doesn't finish the fetch the rest is useless anyway.

Comment: Do the `performSegue` only once you fetch the data.

Comment: Does that require a whole new method and call, or can I do inside of that one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - prepareForSegue doesn't wait for the completionBlock to be completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506559/ios-prepareforsegue-doesnt-wait-for-the-completionblock-to-be-completed)

Comment: Added the code from your link but don't think it fits. Error is "No visible @interface for BNRItemStore declares selector 'fetchfeedAPIChangeDetail:'

Comment: You just adapted (and more like rename) the code in the answer without understanding it. Your error message is quite clear.

Comment: Yes it is clear.  That's what I'm saying.  I don't have my fetch inside of my Item store, therefore I don't think it's a solution that is viable for me.